# It is possible to simplify it more?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Given $\log_m 2 = a$ and $\log_m 3 = b$, I want to calculate $\log_m (64/2.7)- \log_m 60$. Using the logarithm properties, and simplifying, I get $5a + b - \log 27/\log m$, where $\log x$ is the $\log$ in base 10. But it seems it could be more simplified...

Answer (score 4):

we have:
$$
\log_m (64/2.7)- \log_m 60 = \log_m\frac{64 \cdot 10}{27 \cdot 60}=
$$
$$
=\log_m\frac{2^5}{3^4}=5a-4b
$$

Answer (score 3):

**Hint**. Observe that
$$
\frac{\log 27}{\log m}=\frac{\log 3^3}{\log m}=3\cdot\log_m3=3\cdot b
$$